# How do you assign substrings in C?

Tags: c, string, pointers

I'm trying to figure out why this doesn't work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
  char *orig = "Hey you guys.";
  char *str;
  str = &orig;
  while(*str++) {
    if (*str == 'y')
        *str = '@';
  }
  puts(orig);
  return 0;
}
// OUTPUT => "Hey you guys."
// Not "he@ @ou gu@s." as expected.
```

By assigning str = &orig, I thought that str would share the same memory address as orig.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) for sharing memory you want to do `str = orig`, since `str` is already a pointer type.

(2) `orig` is defined as a string literal, **a constant** - so you **cannot modify** the value `"Hey you guys."`, even not when accessing it via `str`, it will result in a run time error.

**EDIT:** Issue #3: In your while loop, you first increase the pointer, and only then checks if it is 'y' and modify. By doing so - **you will miss the first element**. `"yasdf"` will become `"yasdf"` and not `"@asdf"`, as you expect. [well I think that what you expect anyway...]

To achieve what you are after, you can follow this: [using [strcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcpy/) and a buffer, to avoid writing on constant memory]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main ()
{
  char *orig = "Hey you guys.";
  char buff[14]; //the length of orig + 1 byte for '\0'
  char *str = buff; //since str and buff are already pointers
  strcpy(str,orig);
  while(*str) {
    if (*str == 'y')
        *str = '@';
    str++;
  }
  puts(buff);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

- `&orig` is the *address of the pointer*. Perhaps you want `str = orig`. Your compiler should have warned you about a pointer type mismatch here; if it didn't, then turn up the warning level until it does.
- Modifying a constant literal string won't always work. Use `char orig[] = "Hey you guys."`, which copies the literal string into an array called `orig` that you can safely modify.

Answer (score 0):

1. you miss the first element
2. you cannot change a string literal
3. Modified code:

> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
>
> int main ()
> {
>     char orig[] = "Hey you guys.";
>     char *str;
>     str = orig;
>   int i;
>     while(*str){
>       if (*str == 'y')
>             *str = '@';
>       *str++;
>     }
>     puts(str);
>   puts(orig);
>     return 0;
> }
> ```